# Is there a more complete manual for Laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, manual

I’m using Laravel for a project and it’s a great framework, but the manual often falls short.

For example, I’m trying to figure out how to use named routes in the view using Blade, but the [manual](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing#named-routes) explains how to declare them and how to use it in the backend but ends there. I'm pretty sure there's a way to generate a URL using the name of the route.

This isn’t the only problem I’ve ran into where I can’t get the whole story on the manual. Do you know of a place where I can read the more complete manual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You have linked to the official manual. However, there are a lot of great resources out there:

- [Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/)
- [#laravel IRC Chat](http://laravel.io/chat)
- [/r/laravel on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/laravel/)

What you are looking for are the [URL helper functions](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers#urls).

**Edit:** Oh yeah, the [full API](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/) is also available.

Comment: Thanks Ben but the URL helper functions link you sent me was for 5.0, those functions I call in the view are causing errors... I know this wasn't the original question but it would help.

Comment: My mistake. http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers

Comment: Awesome! Thanks Ben, this is exactly what I'm looking for.